# spyOnProperty not delegating to spied on method

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an `ngOnInit` method on my component that looks similar to the following:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.myService.myGetter.subscribe(...);
}
```

I am trying to test this method by mocking my service and spying on my getter. For example, my mocked service looks like:

```
export class MockedService {
    public get myGetter(): Subject<MyData[]> {
        return;
    }
}
```

Inside of my TestBed configuration in my test spec, I include the mocked service in my providers array and inject the service:

```
{ provide: MyService, useClass: MockedService }

let myService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
```

Then, in my actual test, I spy on this property and return the expected value:

```
const serviceSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOnProperty(myService, 'myGetter', 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(sampleData));
```

When it comes time to test the method, I continue receiving:

> Cannot ready property subscribe of undefined

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm spying on the property and returning an Observable for it to spy on.

If I try to change the `return` in my MockedService to something else (return an actual value, say, a string), it seems to work because the error message lets me know that `subscribe` does not exist on `myGetter`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you change your return type of `myGetter` to `Observable<MyData[]>` ?'

Comment: @AmitChigadani, it does not. But you meant on the MockedService, the normal Service, or both?

Comment: From your mocked service, because you show only the mocked service.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, doesn't fix it :(

Comment: Can you show your full test spec?

Comment: This is really all of the code I have in there. At least the important bits. I only have the one method as of now. If I try to debug using Karma, I notice that it is using my mocked service, but the `getter` property is marked as undefined even though I am setting up a spy for it.

Comment: I just wanted to know when you are calling `fixture.detectChanges`. Is it before spy or after spy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172617/discussion-between-user-5842-and-amit-chigadani).